# I need Help with moving partition to NVMe So i can boot from it

Tags: boot, hard-drive, nvme

I currently have a 970 Evo Plus 250GB M.2 NVMe. I also have a system running Ubuntu Linux on HDD, this system also have a space for NVMe drive and I wanna add it and start booting from it instead of from the HDD, is there a way I can move my Ubuntu boot partition from the HDD to the NVMe? and start booting from it and also keep all my Apps? or if there is a better way i would like to try it too so any suggestion is welcomed. I was thinking is there a way i can reinstall Ubuntu to the nvme and choose the manual partition and then use the HDD home partition without its data getting wiped during installation?

[image]

Comment: I have/had Ubuntu on NVMe drive. Someone suggested Kubuntu, so installed to HDD. Liked it, so installed Kubuntu to NVMe in new 30GB partition and copied hidden configuration file as that is all I had really changed. I have all data in separate data partition which I also then mounted in new install.  Do you have separate /home or data partition, so / is smaller? Post this: `sudo fdisk -lu`.  You should be able to do new install & restore from your regular backup. Also good test that backup is complete as you still have install on HDD. Then when drive fails & you have to restore, you know.

Comment: I have added the picture. i do actually have my home on a separate partition

Comment: You are showing older MBR partitioning, but did not post NVMe drive's partitions. Is it gpt or MBR? Any system new enough to support NVMe drive is UEFI. So do you want newer UEFI install or older BIOS/MBR configuration? Do you have another install on NVMe drive? Post NVMe partitions.

Comment: I haven't inserted the NVMe yet I just bought it new to my system. That's why I am asking this question.

Comment: Do you want newer UEFI install or older BIOS type install as you have on HDD? I suggest gpt as newer better than MBR. But with Ubuntu you can boot from gpt with BIOS if you have bios_grub partition or UEFI if you have ESP. When first planning conversion to UEFI, I had both bios_grub for older BIOS system, and ESP for future use with UEFI. But you really only need one or the other. The only place for MBR, anymore is an old BIOS install of Windows which requires MBR.

Comment: I don't understand...Are you saying I Can use GPT partitioning on the NVMe and it would work nicely with my HDD which is MBR? Since I would be reinstalling Ubuntu to the NVMe and only keeping my /home in the HDD

Comment: Yes, each drive can be gpt or MBR. When I first started using gpt in 2010, I has Ubuntu on one 160GB drive with gpt and Windows XP on another 160GB with MBR. Few issues back then, since new, but long resolved. And then Windows totally retired , so no new or re-partitioned drive as MBR. If BIOS the bios_grub is 1MB unformatted with bios_grub flag. It may default to MBR, unless you partition in advance. UEFI/gpt partitioning in Advance, new versions do not need swap partition:
http://askubuntu.com/questions/743095/how-to-prepare-a-disk-on-an-efi-based-pc-for-ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

Your last idea will work perfectly if wanting the old spinner to be the location of the home directory on the new install to keep it used for large media files and such. All you will need to do it that case is delete all the other directories except the /home and re-run `GRUB` to have it remove the entry for the old drive OS or it will refuse to boot upon finding it missing, even though it will have nothing to do with the booting. You need to check to be certain where `GRUB` does get installed but if my experience couple of weeks ago is any indication of it Ubuntu's installer is going to clobber the bootloader installed if any on the `NVMe` drive no matter where you tell it to install to, I told it I wanted the `/dev/sda` it did it to the `NVMe` drive. A good idea before doing it would be to use in `Terminal` `dpkg --get-selections > selections.txt` to save all packages installed to a safe place like the still to be kept /home. Then as root on the new install `dpkg --set-selections < selections.txt` and `apt update` then `apt dselect-upgrade` to have every package installed that was on the old system. Assuming the identical `/etc/apt/sources.list` and `/etc/apt/sources.d` directory contents. The procedure to copy the current install is a little more complicated involving the installer booted, copying the files, changing `UUIDs` in files, multiple `GRUB` installs, it is way easier to do the first method I have described to you already.

Comment: Any way to backup all the apps instead, maybe like in a deb format?

Comment: Should already be there in the `apt` cache the `/var/cache/apt/archives/`. Really no need to backup system files they are easily acquired from the repositories that contain them. Unless you download random .deb files for installing, then you should already have saved them somewhere.

Comment: Sorry to add but how do I go about deleting the other directories except the /home?

Comment: As root or using sudo in front of the command `rm -r /path/to/directory/to/be/deleted`. With the installer before a reboot you should have moved the directory from its `/home/user_name` in that partition to just the `user_name` to the root of the partition. A `mount /dev/sd?? /mnt` then a `mv /mnt/home/user_name /mnt/user_name`. Replacing the ?? with the drive letter and number of the old `/` containing the `/home` to become the new `/home` partition, so the directory structure remains the same after boot into the new install. Everything you see in the new `/home` except user_name is deleted.